# Selecting rows in a DataFrame based on Time of the day?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with `Datetime` as my `index_col`. This data is for 14 days. I want to create two different DataFrames based on the time of day:  data between 6 am and 18 pm of all days as one df and data between 18 pm and 6 am of all days in another df. How to extract?

Below is my Dataframe screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using

for df1

```
df1=df.between_time('06:00', '18:00')
```

for df2

```
df2=df.between_time('18:00', '06:00')
```

more about it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html)